# How can I launch powershell.exe with the "default" colours from the PowerShell shortcut?

Tags: shell, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm attached to the nice blue colour of the PowerShell window when you launch it from one of the pre-installed shortcuts. However, if you manually launch powershell.exe, you don't get these colours, you get black/white :(

This is because the default settings are set on the shortcut (.lnk) file:

[image: PowerShell shortcut colour settings]

I've got a "PowerShell Prompt Here" entry in Explorer context menu, and I'd like it to launch PowerShell using the same nice colours as the usual shortcut; black sucks, and it's confusing to have different coloured windows (especially when I have some old-school command windows open frequently that are also black!).

I've found two problems with trying to set this so far:

1. Setting the colour from within PowerShell seems to only allow certain values (ConsoleColor enum), none of which match the one on the default shortcut.
2. Setting the colour within the PS Profile causes only text written afterwards to honour the new background colour. Adding "cls" causes a nasty flash of the original colour as it starts.

Is there any way to launch PowerShell from a command line (ie. that I can embed in the registry as an Explorer context menu item) that will use the same settings as the shortcut?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a really easy way:

## 1. Add .LNK to your PATHEXT variable.

Start -> run "sysdm.cpl" -> advanced -> Environment Variables

Scroll Down through system variables, double click PATHEXT

Add .LNK; as depicted below:

[image: Path Extension]

## 2 Copy the default "Windows Powershell.lnk"

```
Copy-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk" "C:\Windows\System32\powershell.lnk"
```

## 3. Typing "powershell" from a run prompt will now bring up the default console color/configuration.

You can further customize the .lnk in C:\Windows\System32 to your liking.

Please note that this will only work because you have added the .lnk to the list of acceptable extensions AND c:\windows\system32 is the first item in the search path (PATH system variable) by default.

***This will not customize the console if it is launched via cmd.exe.***

## 4. To make this work from the "Run Powershell Here" context menu, save this as a .reg file and import it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\PowerShellHere\command]
@="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c start powershell -NoExit \"cd '%1';(get-host).ui.rawui.windowtitle = 'Oompa Loompa'\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowerShellHere\command]
@="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c start powershell -NoExit \"cd '%1';(get-host).ui.rawui.windowtitle = 'Oompa Loompa'\""
```

I am using cmd.exe to call "start" which will launch the powershell.lnk and pass the current working directory as an argument. Doesn't seem to work from the address bar yet. I should have gone home 45mins ago, but your problem was fun to solve! :)

Bonus Points: You can thread the commands sent to Powershell. So, if you are looking to modify the Powershell console's title attribute:

```
\"cd '%1';(get-host).ui.rawui.windowtitle = 'Oompa Loompa'"
```

Simply add a semicolon between commands.

Happy shelling

Comment: Interesting idea; though I'm not sure if it'll work from the context menu item; lots of things just give stupid errors like its trying to resolve/understand the command. Will give it a shot though!

Comment: I added a registry entry for you to use, I assumed you used the "PowerShellHere.inf" that's floating around. I will post a link to a revamped PowerShellHere context menu installation when I get the chance.

Comment: When launching from the context menu, it still appears black :( Running the command in the Run dialog works fine, however. Does it work for you? :/

Comment: Scratch that; must've been the env variables not taking effect; rebooted and it works fine! It spawns a black cmd window briefly; I wonder if it's possible to hide that?

Comment: Bonus points if you can make it not say "powershell" in lowercase as the title :-D

Comment: I updated the registry entry and described the process of appending commands. Additionally, you could potentially replace cmd.exe with [hstart.exe](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html) if the blip is really that bothersome. Did you say bonus points? ;)

Comment: I downloaded hstart, but couldn't make it work in the 5 mins I spent; the GUI required a real file to call (not a command), and the option to hide seemed to start a hidden powershell.exe as well as hiding the command prompt! I've been using it all day, and the flash hasn't been as annoying as I expected :)

Comment: Not sure why you have a second reg entry in your answer; though adding to the Background key is good too (though you'll need %v instead of %1) so you can right-click in the blank space in a folder if you're already in it; this is what I do 99% of the time :-)

Comment: I can't award bonus points (ha! can't believe you fell for that ;-)) so I upvoted one of your other correct answers too =)

Comment: Interestingly, I just came to do this on a new computer, and simply creating the registry key to use Start worked fine; I didn't have to do anything with the lnk/pathext! :) `cmd.exe /c start powershell -NoExit -Command "cd '%v'"`

Comment: RE: Step 2, on Windows Server 2012 R2, I found `Windows Powershell.lnk` in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools`

Comment: Regedit should be more like: `cmd.exe /c start powershell -NoExit -NoProfile -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath "%V"` or `cmd.exe /c start powershell -NoExit -NoProfile -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath "%L"`

Answer (score 33):

Edit your profile script (pointed to by $profile) and set the desired colors yourself:

```
# set regular console colors
[console]::backgroundcolor = "darkmagenta"
[console]::foregroundcolor = "darkyellow"

# set special colors

$p = $host.privatedata

$p.ErrorForegroundColor    = "Red"
$p.ErrorBackgroundColor    = "Black"
$p.WarningForegroundColor  = "Yellow"
$p.WarningBackgroundColor  = "Black"
$p.DebugForegroundColor    = "Yellow"
$p.DebugBackgroundColor    = "Black"
$p.VerboseForegroundColor  = "Yellow"
$p.VerboseBackgroundColor  = "Black"
$p.ProgressForegroundColor = "Yellow"
$p.ProgressBackgroundColor = "DarkCyan"

# clear screen
clear-host
```

Comment: I'm adding this answer for others' reference despite your option 2) saying you don't like this.

Comment: I didn't know it was that easily doable. Now that I do, I can't live without it. Colors... In the console window! Amazing! My Linux buddy will die of frustration (console being his strongest argument as he stubbornly works the pains of CMD.EXE still, constantly complaining about the sucky Windows prompt). I absolutely love you right now.

Comment: This can also go into version control and you can share these settings on every PC you use.

Comment: Any idea how to specify exact color values? I tried `[console]::backgroundcolor = "#FF0000"`, `[console]::backgroundcolor = 0xFF0000` (RGB), and `[console]::backgroundcolor = 0xFFFF0000` (ARGB)

Answer (score 13):

I found it very useful to use [concfg tool](https://github.com/lukesampson/concfg) and [scoop](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop) to install colors and fonts for Powershell:

1. Install scoop:

   ```
   iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
   ```
2. Install concfg:

   ```
   scoop install concfg
   ```
3. Install [Solarized theme](https://github.com/lukesampson/concfg/blob/master/preset_examples/README.md#solarized):

   ```
   concfg import solarized
   ```

That's it, thanks to the authors!

Comment: You can just use `irm 'https://get.scoop.sh' -useb | iex` to install Scoop. It's shorter and only uses command syntax.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to do this is with the Registry

```
cd hkcu:/console
$0 = '%systemroot%_system32_windowspowershell_v1.0_powershell.exe'
ni $0 -f
sp $0 ColorTable00 0x00562401
sp $0 ColorTable07 0x00f0edee
```

Comment: Nicely done. Here's a more PowerShell-idiomatic reformulation that doesn't change the current location: `New-Item HKCU:\Console\%systemroot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe |
  Set-ItemProperty -Name ColorTable00 -Value 0x00562401 -PassThru |
    Set-ItemProperty -Name ColorTable07 -Value 0x00f0edee`. To be safe, I've omitted `-Force` (`-f`) from the `New-Item` (`ni`) call, because - regrettably - it [discards any preexisting target key's values](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5444).

Answer (score 6):

Click the system menu (PowerShell icon in the top-left of the window) and click Defaults. You can change the default colors here and it will be respected by the PowerShell Prompt Here command.

From: https://superuser.com/a/523017/109736

Comment: Won't this change them all to black/white, when I specifically wanted to copy the nice blue?

Comment: Clicking Defaults actually brings up a property window and you can change the default to any RGB color there, and that worked for me to change the default color for all PowerShell windows including the "PowerShell Prompt Here" windows.

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `regedit` command to open registry editor
2. Track down `HKEY_CURRENT_USER > CONSOLE` and Backup entire folder by exporting just in case
3. Delete the folder

Restart your Powershell, the color scheme must have reset to defaults.

Note: If you have any other settings related to PowerShell (or Command Prompt, Git Bash etc) which you might want to keep, please further explore Console Folder to delete appropriate keys

Comment: The question is not to reset Powershell colors to default.It is to use the colors from the shortcut when starting from command line.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution (setting the colors in a script that launches as system). May be more than you need (see my own answer):

https://superuser.com/questions/891519/using-psexec-to-launch-powershell-session-as-system-with-specific-window-attribu

Answer (score 0):

Based on @rex-hardin excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13690899/1034782), I improved the regedit content here to add an icon, and use the PowerShell native arguments to start in the right path.

The context-menu is enabled when right-clicking on a directory background, and when right-clicking directly on a directory icon.

Of course, we also run a console with blue background exactly like the default one.

### 1. Add "`.LNK`" extension to `%PATHEXT%` environment variable

This allows system to execute files with `.lnk` extension (hidden extension for shortcuts)

### 2. Copy the default PowerShell shortcut link to system32 as `powershell` file

This allows the `powershell` command to launch our shortcut from `system32` folder (which is in `%PATH%`)

Use explorer (copy+rename) or the command-line below:

```
Copy-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk" "C:\Windows\System32\powershell.lnk"
```

### 3. Add code below to a `powershell_here.reg` file and execute it.

**powershell_here.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\background\shell\PowerShell]
@="PowerShell Here"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\background\shell\PowerShell\command]
@="cmd.exe /c start powershell -NoExit -NoProfile -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\shell\PowerShell]
@="PowerShell here"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\shell\PowerShell\command]
@="cmd.exe /c start powershell -NoExit -NoProfile -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Launch powershell with default blue and white colors in current folder from Explore or Total Commander or Double Commander on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit:

1. Star Menu -> search PowerShell link -> right click on it -> Properties -> Shortcut tab (the one that opens by default) -> modify Start in: -> %CD%

[image]

2. Create a batch file named **ps.bat** somewhere in a folder that is on the system PATH (if you do not have such a folder just make one, let's say *C:\run\cli* and add it to the PATH system environment variable). This batch file has to contain the following command:

   start "" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk"

That's it. Now just type ps in the Explorer's path bar where the current folder is shown or in the command line box of Total Commander or Double Commander,  etc...

On Windows 10, there is no need to modify the PowerShell shortcut from Start Menu and the ps.bat file from above may contain just the following command:

```
start %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```