# How to change the color of power shell editor, for typed commands?

Tags: powershell

Inside powershell when I am type some command it turns to yellow color which is not very visible to me, how can I change that color?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I launch powershell.exe with the "default" colours from the PowerShell shortcut?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690223/how-can-i-launch-powershell-exe-with-the-default-colours-from-the-powershell-s)

Comment: `Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor Black`

Comment: @PetSerAl Please post it as answer, it has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Or even better, use `[console]::ForegroundColor = "Black"`. Also, there are other options, like:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $host.privatedata

ErrorForegroundColor    : Red
ErrorBackgroundColor    : Black
WarningForegroundColor  : Yellow
WarningBackgroundColor  : Black
DebugForegroundColor    : Yellow
DebugBackgroundColor    : Black
VerboseForegroundColor  : Yellow
VerboseBackgroundColor  : Black
ProgressForegroundColor : Yellow
ProgressBackgroundColor : DarkCyan

C:\WINDOWS\system32> $host.ui.RawUI

ForegroundColor       : Green
BackgroundColor       : Black
CursorPosition        : 0,64
WindowPosition        : 0,18
CursorSize            : 25
BufferSize            : 120,3000
WindowSize            : 120,50
MaxWindowSize         : 120,88
MaxPhysicalWindowSize : 265,88
KeyAvailable          : False
WindowTitle           : Administrator: Windows PowerShell
```

Using these settings you can alter your profile so that everytime you launch Powershell they are applied. More on [this](https://www.petri.com/change-powershell-console-font-and-background-colors).

Comment: I ran ur command, but after restarting powershell its again showing yellow color.

Comment: that because you would need to alter your profile to fix this, `Using these settings you can alter your profile so that everytime you launch Powershell they are applied.` Check my answer and the link in it.