# How can I completely reset Powerhsell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'd like to reset *every* single change made to Powershell.  Including permission, window sizes, colors, formatting, etc.  As if I just installed Powershell on my machine, totally virgin.

Is there a way to do this with one command?

Comment: I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690223/how-can-i-launch-powershell-exe-with-the-default-colours-from-the-powershell-s

Comment: Have you tried to simply delete `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` ?

Comment: It might help if you explained what problem you intend to solve.